# Element's side margin overflows parent

Tags: html, css

I want to keep my .side-view__left a certain width (40%) but when I add an element with side margins (0 30px) it suddenly overflows the parent rather than stay in the boundaries. It can be observed that `p` element stays in place but adding a margin on the input pushes it only on the left rather than both sides.

How can I possibly fix it so that input actually has some side margins but stays in its place?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side-view {
  display: flex;
}

.side-view__left {
  flex: 1 1 40%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.side-view__right {
  flex: 1 0 60%;
}

p {
  background: orange;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-view">
  <div class="side-view__left">
    <input />
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="side-view__right">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 100%  + margin = overflow

Comment: I have assumed it would make the element 100% but add side margins. Does that mean I have to wrap it in a container div?

Comment: read the duplicate to find how to add margin with width (*all* the duplicate, not only the title or the first answer)